# Nextjs 13 Post request api is not working in production

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I built API routes in Nextjs. GET and POST request are working fine in localhost. When I built and deploy in IIS, POST request is not working. Instead I receive 500 internal server error. Whereas GET request is working fine without any problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the logs.

Answer (score -1):

You must provide some code to get it solved. The server is crashing with some error on post request, you got to see logs.